# PowerApps ComboBox Multi Select OnChange - how to compare SelectedItems to the data source?

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list, powerapps-canvas

I have an app using a SharePoint List as a data source. There is a multi-select people picker column, which I have in a Combo Box in an Edit Form in my app. Making changes to the SelectedItems and submit form is working fine.

I want a warning whereby if someone makes a change to any fields on the form but hasn't yet submitted it, a text box becomes visible which says "Warning - you have unsaved changes".
Putting a collection in the OnChange, then passing that to the visibility of the warning textbox is working fine for all control types apart from the ComboBoxes. These keep firing after data refresh, even when there have been no changes to the selecteditems.

I have seen others encountering the same problem in various threads, but can't find a workaround that actually works. Best solution I found was to check the ComboBox SelectedItems against the data source, and fire the OnChange collection only if they don't match. But I can't get the syntax correct and keep getting errors saying this formula uses scope.

I'm sure it's something simple but I've spent hours and can't get it. The Concat(ComboContributor.SelectedItems.DisplayName, ",") on the right of the OnChange is working as expected. But trying to get a match from the data source on the left that isn't working.
Help most welcome!

[image: PowerApps OnChange property]

Answer (score 0):

The code should be the following:

Concat(ComboContributor.SelectedItems, DisplayName, ",")

Very minor change and an error that i always make. This link helps:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-concatenate